# Struts2 action which is called in javascript cannot get session object

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts2, uploadify

I have a struts2 action which is called from a javascript(the javascript uses uploadify to upload multiple files):

> ```
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         $("#fileupload").uploadify({
>             'uploader'       : '<%=path%>/js/uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
>             'script'         : 'observationData/Upload.action',
>             ......
>         });
>     }); </script>
> ```

The Upload.action will execute a method which tries to get the session object:

> ```
> public class ObservationDataAction extends ActionSupport{
>        ......
>        public String uploadFile() throws Exception {
>         System.out.println("in function uploadFile()");
>         ......
>         Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
>         System.out.println("Session userID is:"+((SessionUser)session.get("authority.userinfo")).getUserID());
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

But when the javascript calls the Upload.action, it just prints "in function uploadFile()" but cannot get the session userID.

I tried to call Upload.action explicitly by tying the url in the address bar:
"`http://localhost:8080/observationData/Upload.action`", this time I can get the session userID.

I am using struts2.1.6.

This is my struts.xml:

> ```
>    <struts>
>     <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
>     <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action"/>
>     <package name="observationData" namespace="/observationData" extends="struts-default">
>       <action name="Upload" class="observationDataAction" method="uploadFile">
>       </action>
>     </package> <struts>
> ```

And I use org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter as the filter class.

I also tried to implement the SessionAware interface, it doesn't work neither.

Can anyone help point out the problem why in function uploadFile() the session does not work?

More info: 
Here is the function I called to place the user in session:

```
public static final String SESSION_USERINFO = "authority.userinfo";
private static void saveSessionUser(SessionUser sessionUser) {
        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put(SESSION_USERINFO, sessionUser);
    }
```

*Hi I am thinking of a possibility:*
**Is it possible that Ajax/JS create a separate session when they call Upload.action? As a result we cannot get the user in the new session because we set it in the old session?**

Thanks
Xuyuan

Comment: can you please add code formatting for snippets in #1 and #2 ?

Comment: Is the site you're making the Ajax request from on the same domain as the S2 app?

Comment: @stratwine: Sorry that this is the first time I use stackoverflow. I have improved it. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveNewton: The request "observationData/Upload.action" is sent from the same domain as the S2 app.

Comment: Have you confirmed the session cookie is being sent?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Hi Dave, how to confirm that the session cookie is being sent? I don't know much about session cookies and I searched in on the Internet but still not sure.

Comment: Use the browser, Firebug in Firefox, or the built-in Chrome tool, to check the request's content.

Comment: Also, one time I encountered a similar problem when the JSP the javascript ran from didn't have the @page session="true" directive.

Comment: @ferrarifan: I tried but it does not work. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Can you show the code where you put the user into the session?

Comment: What's the value of that constant?

Comment: @DaveNewton: It is public static final String SESSION_USERINFO = "authority.userinfo";

Comment: @Xuyuan Please use the constant across the application to avoid typos like the one you corrected ;) That's what they're for!

Comment: @Xuyuan See [this post](http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2010/03/uploadify-and-session-problems-solved/) and re-try machcm.sz' answer, making sure the session ID is being rendered in the JSP, etc--it looks like uploadify doesn't send cookies.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Hi Dave, thank you very much for linking the post. It seems what the post discuss will have much to do with the problem of my app. I am quite busy these days but will try it latter. I will let you and other folks know my result.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this，add jsessionid param after your script url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileupload").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : '<%=path%>/js/uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : 'observationData/Upload.action?jsessionid=<%=session.getId()%',
            ......
        });
  }); </script>
```

Comment: IMO better to figure out why the normal cookie mechanism isn't working, although this may work. I'd encourage the use of JSP EL over scriptlets, though.

Comment: @machcm.sz: I tried your advice, but it does not work still. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I will try the firebug latter. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @DaveNewton: I tried the firebug a few days ago. When the uploadify process multiple file uploading, nothing happens in "Net" section. So I am guessing the uploadify starts a separate session.

Comment: @Xuyuan Moi need to guess-no cookie or session id, no session. jsessionid should be added after a ";", though, not like a normal request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify uses flash. Every flash application start a new session. So you lose every previous session settings because of the new session started.
You can try a workaround by passing id session to uploadify. 
Assuming you are using Java, you can do like this :

```
$("#uploadify_div).uploadify("settings", "formData", {"idSession",<%=session.getId()%>});
```

In your action or servlet retrieve the id session passed through uploadify and resume the right session, but there are no APIs for that, you need to implements your own by mapping id = session object.

Hope is helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since **uploadify** is using Flash to upload files, My suggestion is to check if there is something wrong with your Flash plugin, or some configurations of Flash. --Is there the same problem on another computer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't tried it on another computer yet but will try. :)